# Method Profiling of Java Mission Control

Tags: java, jfr, jmc

In the method profiling area of JMC, I could observe some methods are annotated with `JIT_COMPILED` and some methods are annotated with `INLINED`.

For those methods annotated with `INLINED`, could I also say they are `JIT_COMPILED` too?